# Why is the voltage positive while the current is decreasing?

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism

The question is:

[image]

The solution is:

[image]

The formula used is:

[image]

So, based on the formula it should be like this:
$$v_L(i)= L\frac{di_L}{dt}$$
$$v_L(i)= +0.4\frac{0.1-0.5}{0.01}$$
**$$v_L(i)=-16V$$**

### **Why did he change the formula?**

The question and answer are from:
FE Exam Review: Electrical and Computer Engineering 1st Edition
by Myron E. Sveum
Publisher : Professional Publications, Inc.
ISBN-10 : 1591260698
ISBN-13 : 978-1591260691

The formula is taken from:
FE Reference Handbook 10.0.1
By NCEES
ISBN 978-1-947801-11-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Simulation: -

[image]

## Transient analysis: -

[image]

## Maths: -

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt} = 0.4 \times \dfrac{-0.4}{0.01} = -16\text{ volts}$$

## Conclusion: -

> *Why is the voltage positive while the current is decreasing?*

It isn't; it's negative.

Comment: Nice answer Andy.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the formula that changed but rather the definition of the inductor voltage in terms of direction.

A positive di/dt causes a positive voltage across the inductor and a negative di/dt causes a negative voltage across the inductor.

A similar question has been answered here [The sign in the formula for the voltage across the inductor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/86724/177428)

Comment: The semi-counterintuitive convention of electrons being negatively charged strikes again. Current flows from + to - and electrons flow from - to +flowing from positive polarity to negative polarity strikes again. In EMF increasing magnitude

Answer (score 0):

Since the current is decreased the inductor tries to keep the current the same-> it can be seen as a variable voltage source which has the same polarity with the battery.